# Progress bar with variable time goals over time

Tags: ios, swift

I am totally new to Swift and a noob at coding, so this might be really simple. I'm creating a progress circle which I want to count up to 100% as 24 hours passes, then the progress resets and counts up until tree days has passed from the original starting point, then one week... So far I got the circle and can controll the progress manually, but I'm not sure where to start to get the time to controll it. Hope someone is able to help.

```
lass ViewController: UIViewController {

let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    let center = view.center

    // Create my track
    let trackLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    let circularPath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center, radius: 100, startAngle: -CGFloat.pi / 2, endAngle: 2 * CGFloat.pi, clockwise: true)
    trackLayer.path = circularPath.cgPath

    trackLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
    trackLayer.lineWidth = 20
    trackLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    trackLayer.lineCap = kCALineCapRound
    view.layer.addSublayer(trackLayer)

    // Create progress circle
    shapeLayer.path = circularPath.cgPath

    shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
    shapeLayer.lineWidth = 20
    shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    shapeLayer.lineCap = kCALineCapRound

    shapeLayer.strokeEnd = 0

    view.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)

    print ("Atempting to animate stroke")

    let basicAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeEnd")

    basicAnimation.toValue = 1

    basicAnimation.duration = 1.2

    basicAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards
    basicAnimation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false

    shapeLayer.add(basicAnimation, forKey: "urSoBasic")
}
```

Comment: I didn't understand actually, What you want ?

Comment: Have you video or gif for same ?

Answer (score 0):

You only need to reconfigure the `duration` so suppose you want it to fill in 60 seconds then refill it again in 10 seconds so you can do ( you can create a function but this for illustration also you can use a timer to easily invalidate it )

```
let basicAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeEnd")

basicAnimation.toValue = 1

basicAnimation.duration = 60

basicAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards

basicAnimation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false

shapeLayer.add(basicAnimation, forKey: "urSoBasic")

DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 60 , execute: {

    self.shapeLayer.removeAllAnimations()

    let basicAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeEnd")

    basicAnimation.toValue = 1

    basicAnimation.duration = 10

    basicAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards

    basicAnimation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false

    self.shapeLayer.add(basicAnimation, forKey: "urSoBasic")

})
```